# Making a <select> show as a scrollable list with only one selection?

Tags: html, html-select

I have a `<select>` list that looks like this.

[image: simplelist]

```html
<select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

I want it to look like this.

[image: multiplelist]

Now, this can be achieved with adding the `multiple` and `size` attributes.

```html
<select multiple size="3">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

But this also allows the user to select more than one element. Just `size="3"` doesn't work (at least in Firefox 28.0); it is displayed as a dropdown list.

The specification [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Attributes) doesn't seem to include any attribute that could do the trick, although it does state that

> Browsers are not required to present a select elements as a scrolled list box.

But is there any way to make it look how I want but still only allow a single selection? A simple enough workaround using JavaScript is also OK for me.

Comment: `size` works in Chrome and also Firefox v28 ;)

Comment: Maybe there was an error in your code ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience, `size="3"` does the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/pU39G/

```
<select size="3">  <!-- Note: I've removed the 'multiple' attribute -->
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Tested on Chrome 33 and Firefox 27. I still don't have Firefox 28, but if it doesn't work there, it seems to be a regression.

Comment: Yeah, tried again and it worked. Now I really wonder what made this happen; I am quite sure it didn't work 10 minutes ago.